# Как создать drawable.xml для такой картинки

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, drawable

Необходимо создать ресурс для заднего фона TextView в drawable такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом заливка маленьких квадратов должна меняться в зависимости от логики приложения. Сама TextView находится в ячейке таблицы, которая в свою очередь скролится и масштабируется. Пробовал использовать Layer List, но не могу понять, как разместить маленькие квадраты относительно друг друга таким образом, чтобы при изменении размеров TextView они тоже изменяли свой размер соответственно. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Мое мнение, вы слишком много требуете от XML drawable. Я бы сделал наследника TextView и рисовал на его канве.

Comment: Попробуйте создать [9 patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch) и пожалуй присоединюсь к предыдущему оратору

Comment: Вы правы. Разобрался с канвасом, все получилось, только есть проблема. Графическая часть отображается, а текст, который сетится в TextView - нет. Можно, конечно, в самом канвасе прописывать тексть, только проблемы со стилями и размерами возникают